# Sending delayed emails with node-mailer on Heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, heroku, nodemailer

I have a MEAN stack web app being hosted on Heroku. I'm using node-mailer (https://github.com/andris9/Nodemailer) to send emails when people create a form, sign up for a form, and a few other things.

Ideally, I would like to send a reminder email one week prior to the date specified on the form.

I have no idea how to accomplish this with node-mailer, and have been scouring google looking for a solution, but come up short.

Is there a good way to send delayed emails with node-mailer? I don't want to switch mailing services if I can avoid it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend not doing this in nodemailer, but to use a scheduler to delay invoking nodemailer. Perhaps something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule